# How to check device is rooted or not Cordova Android programming?

Tags: android, cordova

I have developed Android application using Cordova cross platform language. I want to check whether device is rooted or not. If rooted, then I need to abort or exit the application at run time. Does anyone have any idea or suggestion how I can solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [isDeviceRooted()](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin/blob/master/README.md#isdevicerooted) from [cordova-diagnostic-plugin](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin).

Add the plugin:

```
cordova plugin add cordova.plugins.diagnostic
```

Then for example:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){
    cordova.plugins.diagnostic.isDeviceRooted(function(rooted){ 
        if(rooted){
            navigator.app.exitApp();
        }
    });
}, false);
```

Comment: hey thanks for the answer. but i get confused where to add this code as i have app.js code. below is my app.js but it does not contain the document.addEventListener code.

Comment: is this only for Android ?